# Ruby on Rails - rails console, БД, присвоение данных одного объекта, другому

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель с двумя классами `Project - title, todos` | `Todo - text, isCompleted`.
Я создаю объект `Project`, но оставляю `todos` свободным, потому что этим занимается другой объект, затем создаю `Todo` заполняю `text`. Затем пытаюсь присвоить данные одного объекта другому `project.todos << todo`. Но ничего не выходит. Подтолкните на решение данной проблемы буду очень благодарен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решение в том, что `todos` должно быть не полем в модели Project, а связью `has_many :todos`. Если толчка не хватило - пишите, продолжу :)

Comment: Или, может статься, документации хватит: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations

Comment: Точно! Вы правы. Я прописал в модели Project has_many :todo. А в Todo модели belongs_to :project, required: false. Но он опять ругается на метод и на нил класс. Опять не получается присвоить text Todo модели в todos Project. Как же их присвоить? Может быть метод << не тот

Comment: Скорее всего я понял, у меня два миграционного файла и для Todo и для Project. А как сделать одну миграцию для двух моделей? Спасите, помогите

Comment: скорее всего надо было запихать два класса в одну модель , а не две разные делать, щяс буду пробовать

Comment: Блин, этот серийный `isCompleted` уже примелькался. Это тестовое задание в какой-то конторе что ли?

Comment: `скорее всего надо было запихать два класса в одну модель` - боже мой, о чём вы, @karaname? Сколько таблиц вы создаёте/изменяете внутри одной миграции - это совершенно не важно. Вам у модели Project надо удалить поле todos, и тогда всё заработает, а сейчас наличие этого поля мешает вам обратиться к связи todos, потому как называются они одинаково

Comment: @karaname, сделайте милость, дайте ссылочку - откуда это тестовое задание? Я схожу гайд там напишу уже, что ли, по его прохождению. Заодно выскажу автору всё, что думаю о названии поля isCompleted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример!

Миграции:

```
rails g model Project title:string
rails g model Todo text:text isComplete:boolean project:references
rails db:migrate
```

Модели:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # НЕ!!! :todo, а именно :todos
  has_many :todos, dependent: :destroy
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

В консоли Rails

```
rails c
```

Операции:

```
project = Project.create(title: 'Title')

project.todos.create(text: 'Todo 1', isComplete: false)
project.todos << Todo.create(text: 'Todo 2', isComplete: true)

todo3 = Todo.create(text: 'Todo 3', isComplete: false, project_id: project.id)

project.todos.all
Project.first.todos.where(isComplete: false)
Todo.all.size
```

Если есть ошибка `undefined method`, значит связи указаны не верно.

> Миграции объединять не нужно, в них и есть сила Rails. Каждое изменение, создание модели так и должно находиться в отдельной миграции.

- подробное [описание ассоциаций](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations)